# GetCommTimeouts returns error 87 for network printer

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winapi

For communication with printers we use WinApi methods and handles. Our solution worked properly on Windows 7 (32 and 64 bit versions). Currently, we are migrating to Windows 10 and there is problem with network printers.

The problem is when we try to call `GetCommTimeouts`, update them to what we need and set them back. With code below, if I use direct access to parallel port (path example - `\\.\LPT1`), I can connect to the printer. However, with network printer (path `\\PcName\PrintersName`), code below fails on `GetCommTimeouts`. (In the example is not `SetCommTimeouts`, but it has same behaviour as `GetCommTimeouts`).

It fails with error code 87, which is "Parameter is incorrect". But the structure should be valid and handle is set. The handle is correct, because if I skip Get/SetCommTimeouts functions, printer correctly prints. (not included in code)

```
Private Const INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE As Integer = -1

Private Const GENERIC_READ = &H80000000L
Private Const GENERIC_WRITE = &H40000000

Private Const FILE_SHARE_READ = &H1
Private Const FILE_SHARE_WRITE = &H2

Private Const OPEN_ALWAYS = 4

Private Const FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN = &H8000000

Sub Main()

    Dim handle = CreateFile("\\PcName\PrintersSharedName",
                            GENERIC_READ Or GENERIC_WRITE,
                            FILE_SHARE_READ Or FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                            0,
                            OPEN_ALWAYS,
                            FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
                            0)

    If Not handle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then
        Console.WriteLine("OpenDeviceHandle_Error")
        Console.ReadLine()
        Return
    End If

    Try
        Dim commTimeouts As New COMMTIMEOUTS
        Dim result = GetCommTimeouts(handle, commTimeouts)
        If result = 0 Then
            Dim exception As New Win32Exception
            If exception.NativeErrorCode = 1 Then
                Console.WriteLine("GetCommTimeouts_Correct")
            Else
                Console.WriteLine($"GetCommTimeouts_Error {exception.NativeErrorCode}")
            End If
        End If
    Finally
        CloseHandle(handle)
    End Try
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub


<DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Function CreateFile(lpFileName As String,
                            dwDesiredAccess As UInteger,
                            dwShareMode As UInteger,
                            lpSecurityAttributes As IntPtr,
                            dwCreationDisposition As UInteger,
                            dwFlagsAndAttributes As UInteger,
                            hTemplateFile As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Function GetCommTimeouts(iHandle As Integer, ByRef oCommTimeouts As COMMTIMEOUTS) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Function CloseHandle(hObject As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Private Structure COMMTIMEOUTS
    Dim ReadIntervalTimeout As UInteger          ' Maximum time between read chars
    Dim ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier As UInteger   ' Multiplier of characters
    Dim ReadTotalTimeoutConstant As UInteger     ' Constant in milliseconds
    Dim WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier As UInteger  ' Multiplier of characters
    Dim WriteTotalTimeoutConstant As UInteger    ' Constant in milliseconds
End Structure
```

This same code is working correctly on computer with Windows 7, and even this computer can connect to shared printer, which is connected on Windows 10 machine. On Windows 10, I am not able to connect to shared printer on same computer via the share path.

What I'm not sure, if it's not working because Win10 needs something different for local/shared printers, if it is something Windows 10 related or if there is some error in the code itself. I tried different settings of parameters, I checked multiple times interfaces and structures of WinApi, check if access rights for the printer are same as on Win 7. Everything looks correct for me.

Comment: On window 10, what parameters are in `COMMTIMEOUTS` structure of `Get/SetCommTimeouts`.Because the handle of the printer is valid, the `Get/SetCommTimeouts`function does not work in win10, or the returned parameter is abnormal.

Comment: For more information ,the [link](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/problem-usb-time-outs-by-setcommtimeouts.1430233/) pointed that GetCommTimeouts and SetCommTimeouts are specific to the serial port driver.
They're not general-purpose functions which can be applied to any driver.
You can probably get the effect you want by using overlapped I/O and then
doing a WaitForSingleObject on the event object within the OVERLAPPED
structure. WaitForSingleObject takes a millisecond timeout value.It may be that the driver on window10 does not support `Get/SetCommTimeouts`.

Comment: Do you test on other window 10 computers? And what means with `On Windows 10, I am not able to connect to shared printer on same computer via the share path`.Is there not enough permission?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT Thanks for reply. The structure of COMMTIMEOUTS Im using is in example, default values are all 0. The return values are the same as the input, from both functions. About the serial port driver specification, it worked with LPT port on Windows 7, so there could be chance, that Windows 10 disabled this approach. I tested this behavious on 4 different PC (3x same OS Pro version but different HW, 1 time Enterprise LTSC). For the last comment - I installed shared printer on PC1, and from that pc, I try to connect to \\PC1\printersname and even that doesnt work. Hope this helps.

Comment: it worked with LPT port on Windows 7, so there could be chance, that Windows 10 disabled this approach.  For this situation, I will consult the relevant engineer to confirm if it is a potential issue.

Comment: Thanks, even confirmation that this approach was disabled will help us, as we will know it for sure and we need to look for another approach.

Comment: Refer [Communications Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea#communications-resources), please  set `dwShareMode = 0` and try again . Here is a doc which introduce [Configuring a Communications Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/configuring-a-communications-resource)

Comment: Sorry for late response. I tried this, but it did not help. It looks we might give a try not setting timeouts for shared printer at all and check, if it did not broke something. This looks currently as our only choice, as nothing else is working.

Comment: hi, Crooker Can you retrieve the LPT port in the windows 10 environment?

Comment: By retrieve, you mean window Configure port?

Comment: I mean whether win10 supports LPT port, you can view LPT port in device manager.

Comment: Yes, I can see it in device manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion with Microsoft's relevant engineers, `Get/SetCommTimeouts` should only work for printers connected directly to a PC such as serial or LPT port.  It also should work for Bluetooth. And it should have not worked and now it doesn’t work which is the expected behavior.